# Как задать выполнение определенного кода при любом вызове axios?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Можно как-нибудь глобально в конфиге Axios или где нибудь ещё задать выполнение определенной строки кода при любом вызове axios get/post/patch/put/delete. 
Нужно для того что бы изменять глобальный статус загрузки страницы, а писать TOGGLE_STATUS() в каждом вызове axios get/post не хочется. 
P.S Так же пользуюсь Vuex и Vue-router.

Comment: См. перехватчики запросов (в документации axios). Вообще, всегда полезно заглядывать в оф.доки/учебник, перед тем как задавать вопрос.

Comment: Первый раз слышу про перехватчики, соответственно даже и не знал как начать искать, документация то большая! Спасибо за ответ!